# Unable to install symfony/serializer in Symfony 4.4

Tags: symfony

```
 composer require symfony/serializer
```

returns:

```
Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 1
!!  
!!  In Definition.php line 288:
!!                                                                
!!    Cannot replace arguments if none have been configured yet.  
!!                                                                
!!  
!!  
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-update-cmd

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

Has anyone ever seen this error? I've been debugging for hours, no result. The project is very identical to the Symfony 4.4 boilerplate project and the services seem to be fine. I'm currently debugging since hours, as i heavily depend on the rest bundles and serializers, to get the project up and working.

Thank you!

EDIT: services.yml, i checked with the boilerplate example from symfony, and cant find any differences in config files.

```
# This file is the entry point to configure your own services.
# Files in the packages/ subdirectory configure your dependencies.

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'
            - '../src/Tests/'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
    # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller/'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones
```

EDIT: Here is the snippet from -vvv, interestingly it occurs too if  i try serializer-pack, until the composer file is cleaned, no work can be done.

```html
Running 2.1.9 (2021-10-05 09:47:38) with PHP 7.4.25 on Darwin / 21.4.0
Reading ./composer.json (/Users/christofjori/Desktop/Projects/bon-api/composer.json)
Loading config file /Users/christofjori/.composer/auth.json
Loading config file ./composer.json (/Users/christofjori/Desktop/Projects/bon-api/composer.json)
Checked CA file /opt/homebrew/etc/ca-certificates/cert.pem: valid
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Desktop/Projects/bon-api): git branch -a --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Desktop/Projects/bon-api): git rev-list master..development
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Desktop/Projects/bon-api): git rev-list remotes/origin/master..development
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Desktop/Projects/bon-api): git rev-list remotes/origin/4.4_migration..development
Failed to initialize global composer: Composer could not find the config file: /Users/christofjori/.composer/composer.json

Reading /Users/christofjori/Desktop/Projects/bon-api/vendor/composer/installed.json
Loading plugin PackageVersions\Installer (from composer/package-versions-deprecated)
Loading plugin Symfony\Flex\Flex (from symfony/flex)
Reading /Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/repo/flex/symfony-recipes-flex-main-index.json from cache
Reading /Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/repo/flex/symfony-recipes-contrib-flex-main-index.json from cache
Downloading https://raw.githubusercontent.com/symfony/recipes/flex/main/index.json
Downloading https://raw.githubusercontent.com/symfony/recipes-contrib/flex/main/index.json
[304] https://raw.githubusercontent.com/symfony/recipes/flex/main/index.json
[304] https://raw.githubusercontent.com/symfony/recipes-contrib/flex/main/index.json
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-core.git/): git rev-parse --git-dir
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-core.git/): git remote -v
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-core.git/): git remote set-url origin -- 'https://git.incert.at/libaries/core.git' && git remote update --prune origin && git remote set-url origin -- 'https://git.incert.at/libaries/core.git' && git gc --auto
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-core.git/): git show-ref --tags --dereference
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-core.git/): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-core.git/): git branch --no-color
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-core.git/): git show 'master':'composer.json'
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-core.git/): git -c log.showSignature=false log -1 --format=%at 'master'
Reading composer.json of incert/core (1.52)
Reading /Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/repo/https---git.incert.at-libaries-core.git/ccb15c4498a0ddde03845dabd9de8aa0ff12365f from cache
Importing tag 1.52 (1.52.0.0)
Reading composer.json of incert/core (master)
Importing branch master (dev-master)
Reading composer.json of incert/core (master1)
Importing branch master1 (dev-master1)
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-doctrine-rql/): git rev-parse --git-dir
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-doctrine-rql/): git remote -v
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-doctrine-rql/): git remote set-url origin -- 'https://git.incert.at/libaries/doctrine-rql' && git remote update --prune origin && git remote set-url origin -- 'https://git.incert.at/libaries/doctrine-rql' && git gc --auto
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-doctrine-rql/): git show-ref --tags --dereference
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-doctrine-rql/): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-doctrine-rql/): git branch --no-color
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-doctrine-rql/): git show 'master':'composer.json'
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-doctrine-rql/): git -c log.showSignature=false log -1 --format=%at 'master'
Reading composer.json of incert/doctrine-rql (1.21)
Reading /Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/repo/https---git.incert.at-libaries-doctrine-rql/688d4dec384efbc48f056430136ebc2a65e2ffff from cache
Importing tag 1.21 (1.21.0.0)
Reading composer.json of incert/doctrine-rql (master)
Importing branch master (dev-master)
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-rql-parser54/): git rev-parse --git-dir
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-rql-parser54/): git remote -v
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-rql-parser54/): git remote set-url origin -- 'https://git.incert.at/libaries/rql-parser54' && git remote update --prune origin && git remote set-url origin -- 'https://git.incert.at/libaries/rql-parser54' && git gc --auto
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-rql-parser54/): git show-ref --tags --dereference
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-rql-parser54/): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-rql-parser54/): git branch --no-color
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-rql-parser54/): git show 'master':'composer.json'
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-rql-parser54/): git -c log.showSignature=false log -1 --format=%at 'master'
Reading composer.json of incert/rql-parser54 (1.0)
Reading /Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/repo/https---git.incert.at-libaries-rql-parser54/785f29f1987974968e3730daba20b859bdf3e976 from cache
Importing tag 1.0 (1.0.0.0)
Reading composer.json of incert/rql-parser54 (1.01)
Reading /Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/repo/https---git.incert.at-libaries-rql-parser54/401f12fde384d308f827bc63e58a110f4f63493d from cache
Importing tag 1.01 (1.01.0.0)
Reading composer.json of incert/rql-parser54 (master)
Importing branch master (dev-master)
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-log-explorer-client-php/): git rev-parse --git-dir
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-log-explorer-client-php/): git remote -v
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-log-explorer-client-php/): git remote set-url origin -- 'https://git.incert.at/libaries/log-explorer-client-php' && git remote update --prune origin && git remote set-url origin -- 'https://git.incert.at/libaries/log-explorer-client-php' && git gc --auto
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-log-explorer-client-php/): git show-ref --tags --dereference
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-log-explorer-client-php/): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-log-explorer-client-php/): git branch --no-color
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-log-explorer-client-php/): git show 'master':'composer.json'
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-log-explorer-client-php/): git -c log.showSignature=false log -1 --format=%at 'master'
Reading composer.json of incert/log-explorer-client-php (1.0)
Reading /Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/repo/https---git.incert.at-libaries-log-explorer-client-php/ca8f8385c20ccb3aeb2d042f0a20923ca6b4804d from cache
Importing tag 1.0 (1.0.0.0)
Reading composer.json of incert/log-explorer-client-php (1.01)
Reading /Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/repo/https---git.incert.at-libaries-log-explorer-client-php/0e14852d472050699cddb5e70dee9f9ff67ea49c from cache
Importing tag 1.01 (1.01.0.0)
Reading composer.json of incert/log-explorer-client-php (1.02)
Reading /Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/repo/https---git.incert.at-libaries-log-explorer-client-php/091d2cf864b1cf5a5970f7d49a713568eab077f0 from cache
Importing tag 1.02 (1.02.0.0)
Reading composer.json of incert/log-explorer-client-php (1.03)
Reading /Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/repo/https---git.incert.at-libaries-log-explorer-client-php/be64766d9a7a4d50c6f6203c4665f585d5e61749 from cache
Importing tag 1.03 (1.03.0.0)
Reading composer.json of incert/log-explorer-client-php (1.04)
Reading /Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/repo/https---git.incert.at-libaries-log-explorer-client-php/60354cae3b148201b47d4b2440c02939a6304e7a from cache
Importing tag 1.04 (1.04.0.0)
Reading composer.json of incert/log-explorer-client-php (1.041)
Reading /Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/repo/https---git.incert.at-libaries-log-explorer-client-php/1296c0c5a1fe9e464fdd828c497f0ff53395789b from cache
Importing tag 1.041 (1.041.0.0)
Reading composer.json of incert/log-explorer-client-php (master)
Importing branch master (dev-master)
Downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json
[200] https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Writing /Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/packages.json into cache
Reading /Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/provider-symfony~serializer.json from cache
Downloading https://repo.packagist.org/p2/symfony/serializer.json if modified
Reading /Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/provider-symfony~serializer~dev.json from cache
Downloading https://repo.packagist.org/p2/symfony/serializer~dev.json if modified
[304] https://repo.packagist.org/p2/symfony/serializer.json
[304] https://repo.packagist.org/p2/symfony/serializer~dev.json
./composer.json has been updated
Reading ./composer.json (/Users/christofjori/Desktop/Projects/bon-api/composer.json)
Loading config file /Users/christofjori/.composer/auth.json
Loading config file ./composer.json (/Users/christofjori/Desktop/Projects/bon-api/composer.json)
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Desktop/Projects/bon-api): git branch -a --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Desktop/Projects/bon-api): git rev-list master..development
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Desktop/Projects/bon-api): git rev-list remotes/origin/master..development
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Desktop/Projects/bon-api): git rev-list remotes/origin/4.4_migration..development
Failed to initialize global composer: Composer could not find the config file: /Users/christofjori/.composer/composer.json

Reading /Users/christofjori/Desktop/Projects/bon-api/vendor/composer/installed.json
Loading plugin PackageVersions\Installer_composer_tmp0 (from composer/package-versions-deprecated)
Loading plugin Symfony\Flex\Flex_composer_tmp1 (from symfony/flex)
Reading /Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/repo/flex/symfony-recipes-flex-main-index.json from cache
Reading /Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/repo/flex/symfony-recipes-contrib-flex-main-index.json from cache
Downloading https://raw.githubusercontent.com/symfony/recipes/flex/main/index.json
Downloading https://raw.githubusercontent.com/symfony/recipes-contrib/flex/main/index.json
[304] https://raw.githubusercontent.com/symfony/recipes-contrib/flex/main/index.json
[304] https://raw.githubusercontent.com/symfony/recipes/flex/main/index.json
Running composer update symfony/serializer
Reading ./composer.lock (/Users/christofjori/Desktop/Projects/bon-api/composer.lock)
> pre-update-cmd: Symfony\Flex\Flex_composer_tmp1->configureInstaller
Loading composer repositories with package information
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-core.git/): git rev-parse --git-dir
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-core.git/): git remote -v
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-core.git/): git remote set-url origin -- 'https://git.incert.at/libaries/core.git' && git remote update --prune origin && git remote set-url origin -- 'https://git.incert.at/libaries/core.git' && git gc --auto
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-core.git/): git show-ref --tags --dereference
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-core.git/): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-core.git/): git branch --no-color
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-core.git/): git show 'master':'composer.json'
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-core.git/): git -c log.showSignature=false log -1 --format=%at 'master'
Reading composer.json of incert/core (1.52)
Reading /Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/repo/https---git.incert.at-libaries-core.git/ccb15c4498a0ddde03845dabd9de8aa0ff12365f from cache
Importing tag 1.52 (1.52.0.0)
Reading composer.json of incert/core (master)
Importing branch master (dev-master)
Reading composer.json of incert/core (master1)
Importing branch master1 (dev-master1)
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-doctrine-rql/): git rev-parse --git-dir
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-doctrine-rql/): git remote -v
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-doctrine-rql/): git remote set-url origin -- 'https://git.incert.at/libaries/doctrine-rql' && git remote update --prune origin && git remote set-url origin -- 'https://git.incert.at/libaries/doctrine-rql' && git gc --auto
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-doctrine-rql/): git show-ref --tags --dereference
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-doctrine-rql/): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-doctrine-rql/): git branch --no-color
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-doctrine-rql/): git show 'master':'composer.json'
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-doctrine-rql/): git -c log.showSignature=false log -1 --format=%at 'master'
Reading composer.json of incert/doctrine-rql (1.21)
Reading /Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/repo/https---git.incert.at-libaries-doctrine-rql/688d4dec384efbc48f056430136ebc2a65e2ffff from cache
Importing tag 1.21 (1.21.0.0)
Reading composer.json of incert/doctrine-rql (master)
Importing branch master (dev-master)
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-rql-parser54/): git rev-parse --git-dir
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-rql-parser54/): git remote -v
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-rql-parser54/): git remote set-url origin -- 'https://git.incert.at/libaries/rql-parser54' && git remote update --prune origin && git remote set-url origin -- 'https://git.incert.at/libaries/rql-parser54' && git gc --auto
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-rql-parser54/): git show-ref --tags --dereference
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-rql-parser54/): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-rql-parser54/): git branch --no-color
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-rql-parser54/): git show 'master':'composer.json'
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-rql-parser54/): git -c log.showSignature=false log -1 --format=%at 'master'
Reading composer.json of incert/rql-parser54 (1.0)
Reading /Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/repo/https---git.incert.at-libaries-rql-parser54/785f29f1987974968e3730daba20b859bdf3e976 from cache
Importing tag 1.0 (1.0.0.0)
Reading composer.json of incert/rql-parser54 (1.01)
Reading /Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/repo/https---git.incert.at-libaries-rql-parser54/401f12fde384d308f827bc63e58a110f4f63493d from cache
Importing tag 1.01 (1.01.0.0)
Reading composer.json of incert/rql-parser54 (master)
Importing branch master (dev-master)
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-log-explorer-client-php/): git rev-parse --git-dir
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-log-explorer-client-php/): git remote -v
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-log-explorer-client-php/): git remote set-url origin -- 'https://git.incert.at/libaries/log-explorer-client-php' && git remote update --prune origin && git remote set-url origin -- 'https://git.incert.at/libaries/log-explorer-client-php' && git gc --auto
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-log-explorer-client-php/): git show-ref --tags --dereference
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-log-explorer-client-php/): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-log-explorer-client-php/): git branch --no-color
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-log-explorer-client-php/): git show 'master':'composer.json'
Executing command (/Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/vcs/https---git.incert.at-libaries-log-explorer-client-php/): git -c log.showSignature=false log -1 --format=%at 'master'
Reading composer.json of incert/log-explorer-client-php (1.041)
Reading /Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/repo/https---git.incert.at-libaries-log-explorer-client-php/1296c0c5a1fe9e464fdd828c497f0ff53395789b from cache
Importing tag 1.041 (1.041.0.0)
Reading composer.json of incert/log-explorer-client-php (master)
Importing branch master (dev-master)
Downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json
[200] https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Writing /Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/packages.json into cache
Reading /Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/provider-symfony~serializer.json from cache
Downloading https://repo.packagist.org/p2/symfony/serializer.json if modified
[304] https://repo.packagist.org/p2/symfony/serializer.json
> pre-pool-create: Symfony\Flex\Flex_composer_tmp1->truncatePackages
Updating dependencies
Generating rules
Resolving dependencies through SAT
Looking at all rules.

Dependency resolution completed in 0.001 seconds
Analyzed 260 packages to resolve dependencies
Analyzed 656 rules to resolve dependencies
Generating rules
Resolving dependencies through SAT
Looking at all rules.

Dependency resolution completed in 0.000 seconds
Lock file operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
Installs: symfony/serializer:v4.4.41
  - Locking symfony/serializer (v4.4.41)
Writing lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Reading ./composer.lock (/Users/christofjori/Desktop/Projects/bon-api/composer.lock)
> pre-operations-exec: Symfony\Flex\Flex_composer_tmp1->recordOperations
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
Installs: symfony/serializer:v4.4.41
Reading /Users/christofjori/Library/Caches/composer/files/symfony/serializer/6fa9ff63c92acff28fbdaf7744e7bb64fefcbebe.zip from cache
  - Loading symfony/serializer (v4.4.41) from cache
  - Installing symfony/serializer (v4.4.41): Extracting archive
Executing async command (CWD): '/usr/bin/unzip' -qq '/Users/christofjori/Desktop/Projects/bon-api/vendor/composer/tmp-a61c55d8c539df185725083347debffb' -d '/Users/christofjori/Desktop/Projects/bon-api/vendor/composer/3247dc55'
Executing async command (CWD): rm -rf '/Users/christofjori/Desktop/Projects/bon-api/vendor/composer/3247dc55'
> post-package-install: Symfony\Flex\Flex_composer_tmp1->recordFlexInstall
Downloading https://packagist.org/downloads/
[201] https://packagist.org/downloads/
Package doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package doctrine/reflection is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use roave/better-reflection instead.
Package symfony/inflector is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use EnglishInflector from the String component instead.
Generating autoload files
> post-autoload-dump: PackageVersions\Installer_composer_tmp0->dumpVersionsClass
composer/package-versions-deprecated: Generating version class...
composer/package-versions-deprecated: ...done generating version class
99 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
> post-update-cmd: Symfony\Flex\Flex_composer_tmp1->update

Run composer recipes at any time to see the status of your Symfony recipes.

> post-update-cmd: @auto-scripts
> auto-scripts: Symfony\Flex\Flex_composer_tmp1->executeAutoScripts
Executing script cache:clear
Executed script cache:clear  [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 1
!!  
!!  In Definition.php line 288:
!!                                                                
!!    Cannot replace arguments if none have been configured yet.  
!!                                                                
!!  
!!  
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-update-cmd

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

Comment: Can you show us your services.yaml ?

Comment: added the file.

Comment: same happens if i try to install symfony/serializer-pack

Comment: Can you run "composer req symfony/serializer -vvv" with verbosity and add the result here

Comment: -vvv output added.

Comment: @jo-chris error is thrown when composer runs `c:c`, so I suggest simply `rm -rf var/cache/dev` and try again.

Comment: If a manual delete of the cache doesn't do it, you want to give it a try with `--no-scripts`. But you might end up with the same problem later on.

Comment: i can install it with --no-scripts, but receive the error afterwards. any suggestions?

Comment: nuked all packages, reinstalled them and removed one from our own which was unused. this fixed it. Thank you!